# Unable to unlock keyboard on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, acer-aspire, lock

I am unable to unlock keyboard on my laptop which is acer's Aspire E 15 modeland having Windows 7 installed. Somehow keyboard is locked and none of the button on keyboard is working now.

I verified whether "Turn on Filter Keys" is checked. It is not. I also tried some other options which I found on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUC6dkgjG0o) like pressing ctrl button while holding another ctrl button; pressing F4 button while holding Function button.

But none of 'em worked. Anything I am still missing ?

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again? Can you get into the BIOS? If it's a Windows setting, it won't change how the keyboard works before Windows boots.

Comment: @MichaelFrank turning off laptop ? Yes I did.